# google analytics - event tracking without affecting bounce rate

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm studding a way of using Google Analytics to track Ad impressions/clicks.
Looks like **event tracking** is the way to go.
Tracking clicks it's easy to implement. My doubt resides on impressions:

- using **event tracking** on page load will cut down my bounce rate to 0
- using a second profile doesn't look elegant (leave it for last resource)

GOAL: John loads page A and leave. Count 1 for impressions and 1 for bounce rate as it should.

Is there a way of doing it with Google Analytics?

Comment: It will be very helpful to reduce bounce rate.   http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/11/reduce-bounce-rate-without-plugin/  read here and get  your JS

Answer (score 11):

(Edited to reflect new non-interaction option)

Yes, it will absolutely reduce your bounce rate to somewhere near zero (if you do not explicitly set the new non-interaction flag).

For past data, the closest proxy to bounce rate for when every page sends multiple hits to Google Analytics is using 'Visit Depth'; the % of visitors who view exactly 1 page is a close proxy for bounce rate in the instance you're describing, since it doesn't take into account event tracking.

### UPDATE Nov 2011

 There is a new feature in Google Analytics event tracking called "[non-interaction events](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#non-interaction)", where you can designate an event as being a non-interaction by passing `true` as a fifth argument (or, six item in the array).

Example:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Category", "Action", "Label", 3, true]);
```

This will instruct Google Analytics to not count the event as an interaction for the sake of bounce tracking.

Comment: I already searched entire web, there's no way to do it without a way around. I think I'll use a second profile... Google should change the **event tracking** method. Let webmasters decide if certain event should count or not as a real event.

Comment: @cmancre Can you let me know if a 2nd profile works? GA can occasionally be quirky about how it treats hits that are filtered out, so its possible it might not work as you intend.

Comment: Thank you i have searched all around the web to find an example of all the data in the function. This is the only place, in the whole world wide web