# What is causing low bounce rate?

Tags: events, analytics, tracking

Hi stackflow community

I'm looking for a way to fix my low bounce rate issue. I'm sure a few other webmaster have or have had the same issue so hopefully it should help them as well.

Since the implementation of event tracking on the website the analytics bounce rates have dropped. I've tried to implement the fixes suggested here: [google analytics - event tracking without affecting bounce rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301123/google-analytics-event-tracking-without-affecting-bounce-rate)

But still have had no luck getting proper stats on the bounce rate. 
This is the websites source: view-source:http://www.quatermain.co.za/

Are you able to see what could be causing the issue?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.  Suggest migration to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Google Analytics - low bounce rate is a *generally* a **good thing** for most websites.

However, in my personal opinion - bounce rate on its own is a rather pointless metric.
A high bounce rate might mean the visitors find the information they need on the landing page.
A low bounce rate might mean the visitors cannot find the information easily and navigate around a lot.

So what you need to do is set up goals for your website and track those to figure out what visitors are doing on your site, and do they find what they need - or do they wander aimlessly and ultimately leave before triggering the "goal" aka the "point of their visit" on your website.
So you need to analyze the navigation of the visitors, what are their landing pages - where do they go from there and ultimately - do the visitors exit from where you want them to exit.

For example; A webshop want a low bounce rate. However the want that in combination with triggering the goals of a sale.

Based on the website linked, I would think it is the "book now" button that's the important part of the website - the "point" so to speak.
So you'll need to measure the number of visits that trigger a booking and react to that number.

But again - generally speaking - if your bounce rate is low - that's normally a good thing

Comment: It's a bounce rate that's too low. Like 2%. It's a problem not a good thing.

Comment: Too low for what?  Why is it not a good thing?  Do you think the measurement is erroneous?

Comment: A bounce rate of 2 % is only a problem if it means the visitors never find what they need. As mentioned - you'll need to add more metrics to your analysis. Navigation path, do they reach the goal and so on.

Comment: The measurement is incorrect. Once I implemented event tracking the bounce rates dropped

Comment: I have seen a similar problem with low bounce rates.  a year or so ago I had a ~46% BR, but now its 7% without a ton of changes.